# How do I configure the path of my python scripts so I can open it with cmd and python interpreter

Tags: python

I have been stuck on this for a while. I've read many blogs but still struggling to understand how to set the path in my advanced settings in environment variables so that I can run my scripts in both cmd and python interpreter.

Comment: In what OS you are?

Comment: Can you please paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for this would be, setting the environment variable for python by following the steps below:

Click on:- My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables 
Then under system variables, create a new Variable called PyPath.
In this variable I have C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;

This would work for windows

Comment: Thanks Ive added a new variable called PYpath how would I check this is now been corrected. How would I execute my scripts on cmd

Comment: def happyBirthday ():

 print("Happy birthday to you !")
 print("Happy birthday to you ")
 print("Happy birthday to louis")
 print("Happy birthday to you")

happyBirthday()

Comment: Im trying to execute this function alling this script using cmd. This is my first script

Comment: Go first to your command prompt, and type python and see what you get in return, you should get python and its version

Comment: when i type in python the cmd output is not recognised as an internal or external command. but when i type in py it goes into python 3.6

Comment: ok so when you type py you can enter into python right ? then just type print("hi hello world") you will get output as >>>hi hello world

Comment: If these are working fine then your python is working completely fine and you can start writing code, also you can upvote my answer if you think it helped ! let me know if you have any questions

Comment: this wasnt a problem i could get into python using cmd. the problem was not being able to run the script into cmd what procedures would i need to do this thanks again

Comment: Are you not able to run anything in cmd ? not even print("hello world')